# how to call 'onchange' and 'onblur' js event name in same input?

Tags: javascript

As the following, in codeigniter view, I want to call twice js events- 'onchange' and 'onblur' function

Is it possible? How can I call?

Comment: We'll need your code to fix your problem. Please post your code.

Comment: Use `addEventListener`

Comment: i think onkeyup function is enough instead of using these two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below code.

```html
<html>

<bods >
    <input type="text" value="here is a text field" onblur="alert('Blur Event!')" onchange="alert('Change Event!')"  >

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onchange="alert('ok')" onblur="blurfunction()">
          <script>
             function blurfunction() {
             
               var x = document.getElementById("fname");
               x.value = x.value.toLowerCase();
             }
             
             function keyupcall(){
               var x = document.getElementById("fname");
               x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
             }
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the methods will called at the same time, I am not sure for what purpose you required it.
But you can write both the method as following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
  $("input").blur(function(){
    alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text">
    <p>Write something in the input field, and then click outside the field.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not valid answer for this question. Please read question carefully then take action